# HTML Form Tag creating extra space in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am having an issue with   tags in IE 7 and 8
there are some unwanted spaces which I am experiences on these browsers my css snippet.

```
form{margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;}
```

This css fails only on IE 7 and 8 Please let me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display : inline;` in the css as follows:

```
form{margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in IE7&8 where if a form is preceded by an unclosed `<p>` tag, it will create an extra box above the form. Closing the `<p>` should fix the issue.